# How to calculate leap year in jalali calendar?

Tags: javascript, jalali-calendar

As you know, there is a leap every four years in the Jalali calendar (There are, of course, a few exceptions)

And instead of having 365 days a year, it has 366 days :)

And the other problem is that some months are 29 days and some months are 30 days and some months 31 :|

I use moment library for generating these dates ( of course using fa method)

This website which called [تقویم](https://8box.ir/%D8%AA%D9%82%D9%88%DB%8C%D9%85) is doing it very well.

```
var moment = require('moment-jalaali')
moment().format('jYYYY/jM/jD')
```

Now my question is how to identify which months are 29 and 30 and 31
and which year is leap?

Answer (score 8):

In my previous project I had the same problem, You must use this method to do this

This function isn't in javascript But this algorithm work very good for your leap year

```
internal static bool IsLeapYear(int y)
{
    int[] matches = { 1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 22, 26, 30 };
    int modulus = y - ((y / 33) * 33);
    bool K = false;
    for (int n = 0; n != 8; n++) if (matches[n] == modulus) K = true;
    return K;
}
```

Comment: Yes I use it in my previous project

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **JavaScript version** of Sina Rahmani's answer (the y / 30 should round down for it to work properly in JavaScript):

```
function isLeapYearJalali(year) {
    const matches = [1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 22, 26, 30];
    const modulus = year - (Math.floor(year / 33) * 33);
    let isLeapYear = false;

    for (let i = 0; i != 8; i++) {
        if (matches[i] == modulus) {
            isLeapYear = true;
        }
    }

    return isLeapYear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same JS code, Just a little fancy!

```
function isLeapYearJalali(year) {
   const matches = [1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 22, 26, 30];
   const modulus = year % 33;
   return matches.includes(modulus)
}
```